# Whats difference between websocket and flask-streaming from scenario aspect

Tags: python, flask, websocket, streaming

I'm developing a BS kafka monitor tool. The program will listen to a kafka topic, and constantly output the new message from that topic. So which is the best approach to send those message constantly to browser side?

The program uses flask, so currently I'm using the stream_with_context to send new message to browser side. This works for now, but I wonder if this is the correct scenario to use stream_with_context since most usage case is for downloading and video streaming? or maybe I should use websocket?

```py
@read_controller.route('/v1/listenkafka/<string:kafkaId>', methods=['GET'])
def start_stream(kafkaId):
    try:
        mykafka_json = eval(my_storage.get(kafkaId))
        mykafka = kafkaserver(ip=mykafka_json['ip'], id=kafkaId, port=mykafka_json['port'])
        return Response(stream_with_context(mykafka.consume_topic(mykafka_json['topic'])))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{e}")
        return jsonify(f"{e}"), 400
```

```py
#The generator listen to kafka and feed to stream

def consume_topic(self, topic, groupid='test-consumer-group'):
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic,
                             group_id=groupid,
                             bootstrap_servers=[f"{self.ip}:{self.port}"])
    print(f"Topic: {topic}@{self.ip}:{self.port} starts steaming at {datetime.now()}")
    try:
        for messages in consumer:
            mykafka_json = eval(my_storage.get(self.id))
            print(mykafka_json)
            if mykafka_json['flag']:
                my_storage.delete(self.id)
                return
            else:
                message = {'topic':messages.topic,
                           'partition':messages.partition,
                           'offset':messages.offset,
                           'key':messages.key,
                           'value':messages.value}
                print (message['value'])
                yield message['value']
    except StopIteration as e:
        #TODO:: handle return
        print(e)
    finally:
        print(f"Topic-{topic} finish at {datetime.now()}")
```

So, should I use stream_with_context in this scenario or should I switch to use websockt?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now I undertand。

The stream_with_context actually will return  ALL contents from beginning at each time the front request.

So it is a tool for downloading, not for constantly pushing new data from server to client

Eventually, I chosed flask-socketIO, it is a better choice than websocket, but you need to study the sample to understand how it works...The doc miss some details...